# Sql Loader Control file with " "

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader

I am currently loading a .csv file into the tables using a sqlloader with a control file but at the end in the table I am getting double quotes in them, how to prevent them from loading ? I want only the data to be loaded into the tables? This is the .ctl file:

```
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE omh_esn_model_details_06nov
append
fields terminated by ","  trailing NULLCOLS
(
ESN_NO char(200),
MAKER constant "ZGH",
MODEL_NO constant "M81",
OFFER constant "OFFER"
)
```

This is the .csv file contents are the values are row by row:

```
ESN No 
A10000428A5789 
A1000046685985 
A1000484526948
```

finally i am getting like this in the table after inserting

```
"A10000428A5789" ZGH  M81  OFFER
```

Comment: try to add optionally enclosed by X'22' in control file

Comment: Worked for me with your control file and data on 11g

Comment: @Gary_W it work's but i get data in table like this "A10**********"

Comment: @algor can you please explain why to add them? and what's going wrong?

Comment: You said you got double quotes in the table.  Those are asterisks after the A10 and that's whats in the data.  Edit your original post to show what you expect.  Your `CONSTANT` data also has asterisks?

Comment: @algor it didnot work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, the file i am loading has ^M characters , so that has been the problem.Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Something still isn't adding up.  How are you getting rid of the "ESN No" text in the data file?  In the meantime  try changing this line:

```
fields terminated by ","  trailing NULLCOLS
```

to this:

```
fields terminated by ","
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
trailing NULLCOLS
```

Comment: i skip the header file by skip =1 when i am loading

Comment: I didn't see the SKIP=1 line in the control file.  There are no double-quotes in the data?

Comment: sqlldr USERID=user/user@password data=/user/direc/bau2658.csv CONTROL=/user/direc/OMH.ctl log=/user/direc/OMH2.log skip=1..(through this in putty i insert it) and 'NO' there are no double -quotes in the file.

Comment: Could there be a trigger on the table that is formatting ESN_NO?

Comment: No there is no trigger..i checked with a .txt file with a this "|" as delimiter it worked fine... i want to know why its happening with a .csv file.